# How to not stretch an image of a button in a table | ANDROID

Tags: android, image, button, stretch

I have a problem:

I have a table with a row and two cells. I splitted the table in the half of the screen. In each cell is a button with an own button style (android:background). Each button style includes an image. But the problem is that the image (the button) is stretched. I don't know what I must change so that the image is not stretched anymore.

Here is the table layout:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/aa" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bb" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And here is the button style:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/aa1"
            android:state_pressed="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/aa2" />
 </selector>
```

What must I change so that the image isn't stretched? The proportion of the image should be available and it should be splitted in the half of the screen.

THANKS for help. That's very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout: use a `ImageButton` instead of `Button` and add the image in `android:src` attribute.

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Output:

[image]